# Microsoft SqlServer Management: method not found creating a ServerConnection

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, smo

Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects 161.47027.0

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 5.0.0

After upgrading Microsoft.Data.SqlClient from 4.1.0 to 5.0.0
I got this error creating a ServerConnection object:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;

var serverConnection = new ServerConnection("localhost", "sa", "mypwd");
```

> System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'Void
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_Encrypt(Boolean)

It looks for a not implemented set_Encrypt method inside a Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder

Does it mean Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects has not been  updated yet to support Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 5.0.0?

If so do I need to wait for this update before I can upgrade Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 5.0.0 into my project?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1402)?

Comment: You should be using a username and password.  Instead use credentials by using a connection string with property "Trusted_Connection=Yes".  See https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also upgrade the ServerManagementObjects reference to 170.7.0-preview to resolve. Apparently the issue is with the smo library not the sqlclient library.
https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1702

> Their code should be backwards compatible, but they need to be recompiled against MDS 5.0

Answer (score 1):

Below is MyConnectionString"

```
"Server=tcp:xxx.xxxx.windows.net;Authentication=Active Directory Default;Database=TestDB;TrustServerCertificate=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
```

Had the error:

> Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_Encrypt(Boolean)'. `When using`Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 5.0.1.`

Fixed By: Downgraded the package `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` to 4.1.0.and Using `Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects` 161.47021.0.

Fixed the error. Thank you for this post.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same `MissingMethodException` when attempting the update of `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 4.1.0 to 5.0.0` in our system.  Simply `updating Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` - independently of Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects - resulted in the exception when constructing the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection` using SQL Server Authentication (not Windows Authentication).

This snippet `causes` the MissingMethodException if using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 5.0.0 (worked in 4.1.0):

```
      Return New ServerConnection With {
        .ApplicationName = My.Application.Info.Title,
        .ServerInstance = connectionParameters.DataSource,
        .ConnectTimeout = connectionParameters.ConnectionTimeout,
        .LoginSecure = False,
        .Login = connectionParameters.UserName,
        .Password = connectionParameters.Password
      }
```

For now, we are holding off on updating `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`, but went ahead with the `Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects` update `(161.47021.0 to 161.47027.0)`.  I am hopeful that an upcoming `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` version will fix this issue.