# SMO MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, smo, .net-4.8, missingmethodexception

I have already raised this with Microsoft Support, but somehow this takes forever, so I thought I throw this in here and see if anyone has already encountered (and maybe solved?) this:
I have a C# application that uses both Microsoft.SqlSer.SqlManagementObjects (currently 161.47027.0) and Microsoft.Data.SqlClient (currently 5.0.0.0). Since upgrading the SqlClient a while back, my SMO library is broken completely. The exception I keep getting is:

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_Encrypt(Boolean)'.     
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionSettings.GetConnectionString()     
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionSettings.get_ConnectionString()     
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.InitSqlConnectionObject(Boolean setConnectionString, Boolean removeIntegratedSecurity)     
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection..ctor()     
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager..ctor(String name)     
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server..ctor(String name)     
at DBHelper.GeneralDBHelper.GetServerSettings(MSSQLParameter param)
```

The code in question looks like this:

```
Server Srv;
Srv = new Server(param.DeviceName);
```

Where param.DeviceName is a string holding the server name.

Does anyone have a useful idea?

thx

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow hannes! may we know if this a [tag:net-core] or [tag:.net]? it may affect the answer to your question. also, have you tried to use newer SqlManagementObjects? - see [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73457750/microsoft-sqlserver-management-method-not-found-creating-a-serverconnection). best of luck!

Comment: You have to use the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` version that `Microsoft.SqlSer.SqlManagementObjects` references.

Comment: @BagusTesa Sorry, I should have mentioned that: I am targeting .Net Framework 4.8
Alberto I can't use the version referenced directly (3.0.0.0), I need the Data.SqlClient for other things too, and I need the 5.0 version for those parts of the software. Besided, The package clearly states "SqlClient >=3.0.0.0"

Comment: Taken from [here](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1702). The Encrypt property seems to have changed from a boolean to an enum with v5 for the SqlClient and the version of SMO you use still expect is to be a boolean.

Comment: There are preview nuget packages for SMO available that may be compatible SqlClient 5. Its mentioned atleast in the change log https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/sqlmanagementobjects/main/Nuget/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Thanks @Ralf that looks great, I will test that version out